# Can't add foreign key Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables (regions & categories) , I wanted to have a foreign key in regions table  this is my migration file :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('nom');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('vote');
        $table->string('securite');
        $table->integer('idCat')->unsigned()->change();
        $table->foreign('idCat')->references('idCat')->on('categories');
        $table->timestamps();
         });


}
```

the table 'categorie' looks like this :

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        //$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('idCat');
        $table->String('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

But I got this error : Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'idCat'
  doesn't exist in table (SQL: alter table `regions` add constraint `regions_

  idcat_foreign` foreign key (`idCat`) references `categories` (`idCat`))

Canyou help me please ?

Comment: are you doing the migrations in the correct order (first categories, then regions)? why the change() method on the column in regions?

Comment: I do not know exactly , I just run 'php artisan migrate:fresh' Command

Comment: check the timestamps in the names of the migration files.... Which one is first?

Comment: first categories , then regions

Comment: See my answer below. It works for me... Just get rid of the change...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you get rid of the change(), the column is not there yet.. The following code works perfectly for me...

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class Test extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('idCat');
            $table->String('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('regions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nom');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->integer('vote');
            $table->string('securite');
            $table->integer('idCat')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('idCat')->references('idCat')->on('categories');
            $table->timestamps();
        });


    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('regions');
        Schema::drop('categories');
    }
}
```